# How do I create a link to a list of records where field X contains Y in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the exact result I want if I change...

```
def index
 @listings = Listing.all
end
```

to...

```
def index
 @listings = Listing.where("general_use == 'Industrial'")
end
```

... in listings_controller.rb

The Listings index view shows a list of all Listings where the general_use field contains the word Industrial.  However, I can no longer use the index view to show all listings if I do this.

I want to add a link at the top of my listings index view that narrows the listings down from "all" to just the "industrial" listings.

I don't know what code should go in any, all or none of the following places:

- controllers\listings_controller.rb
- helpers\listings_helpers.rb
- models\listing.rb
- views\listings\index.html.erb
- config\routes.rb

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chip

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use a GET parameter:

```
def index 
    if params[:use]
       @listings = Listing.find(:all, :conditions => {:general_use => params[:use]})
    else
       @listings = Listing.all
    end
end
```

In your view, add a link to `?use=industrial` and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! It is working perfectly. You can see your code in action at http://www.commercialonerealtors.com/listings where I have links to Industrial, Land, Multi-Family, etc.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Chip, You're welcome. Can you accept my answer by clicking on the hollow checkmark to the left? Thanks!